# Why are systemd scripts not producing the expected results at boot, but correctly afterwards?

Tags: systemd, raspbian, services, gpio

I have a Raspberry Pi on Raspbian Stretch and I want to enable some GPIO pins at boot time.

I wrote the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=GPIO23 exported as output, value off

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo "23" > /sys/class/gpio/export'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value'
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
Alias=gpio23.service
```

After login via SSH, I check the result:

```
pi@Hi-Fi:~ $ systemctl status gpio23
● gpio23.service - GPIO23 exported as output, value off
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpio23.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
pi@Hi-Fi:ls /sys/class/gpio/
export  gpiochip0  unexport
```

Since it hasn't been run (or it didn't work as intended), I start the service manually:

```
pi@Hi-Fi:~ $ sudo systemctl start gpio23
[sudo] password for pi:
pi@Hi-Fi:~ $ systemctl status gpio23
● gpio23.service - GPIO23 exported as output, value off
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpio23.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jan 01 19:31:12 Hi-Fi systemd[1]: Starting GPIO23 exported as output, value off...
Jan 01 19:31:12 Hi-Fi systemd[1]: Started GPIO23 exported as output, value off.
pi@Hi-Fi:~ $ ls /sys/class/gpio/
export  gpio23  gpiochip0  unexport
```

Now it works.

How can I make it work immediately as intended?

Comment: you will need to add the service to `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη but the other services run fine and they are not in rc.local. Moreover, rc.local is executed ITSELF through a systemd service.

Comment: I see, did you enabled systemctl to auto startup that service ? using `sudo systemctl enable gpio23`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη yes I did, as you can see the service is enabled: "vendor preset: enabled"

Comment: Check the logs with `journalctl -n 100 -xu gpio32`  you might need to remove `StandardOutput=null` and reboot before doing so. It could be that it is executing too quickly (before the gpio kernel module is loaded).

Comment: but it's `dead` status, not `active`. the issue with the service itself ~ how come systemctl gonna re-enable it if it's already dead status

Comment: as i see you already started the service manually but with dead status ! check the service logs. i believe the issue with the service itself since it's not active.

Comment: `rc.local`‽  This is another datum to support the recommendation to take comment answers with a huge sackful of salt.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη of course it's dead, since it's a "oneshot" service!

Comment: @MichaelDaffin no entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> [Install]
> Alias=gpio23.service
> ```

It's as simple as noting that there's no `WantedBy` setting in that section.  You've told systemd to enable the service, but not actually described which target should want it when it is enabled.

> ```
> StandardOutput=null
> ```

It is not wise to do this as an everyday practice.  Let standard output be logged until it becomes an actual problem to do so (which it clearly is far from being in the case of a few `echo` commands).

> ```
> ExecStart=/bin/bash …
> ```

And, similarly, don't name the Bourne Again shell unless you are explicitly relying upon Bashisms, which (again) you are not with just some `echo` commands.

A decade ago, the Debian and Ubuntu people went to quite some lengths to take the Bourne Again shell out of the system bootstrap process wherever it was possible, replacing it with the Almquist shell which had far less initialization overhead in non-interactive mode, which sped up bootstrap markedly.  Idly using `/bin/bash` all over the place — in systemd service units no less! — instead of `/bin/sh`, undoes that good work.

Comment: That did the trick. I used Bash because I thought that /bin/sh was a link to /bin/bash... but now I modified it as recommended.